# Angular 5 role based routing

Tags: angular5

I've a website with a home page defined in my routing module as:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent
}];
```

Now I would like to display a different home page for admin users (a Dashboard page).
Could I change the "component" called based on the user's role?

in pseudo code something like:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  IF UserRole = 'Admin'
     component: DashboardComponent
  ELSE
     component: HomeComponent
}];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do that there is something called Angular Guards Route https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

Comment: That is not what OP asked for. I read that article. It's about Role Guard - guarding a route by Role(like in common case we do by Auth State), it's not about redirecting to different components by Role

Answer (score 5):

Tutorial Link in the @andrea06590 answer has very brief overview for Authentication and Authorization based routing.
In a short way , someone can use the following way:

1. Use canActivate property and pass it a service class which implements CanActivate Interface.
2. use data object property to pass the role to AuthGuard service.

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path : ''  , redirectTo : '', pathMatch: 'full' , canActivate : [ RedirectGuardService ] },
  { path : 'admin' , component : AdminComponent , canActivate : [AuthGuardService] , data : { role : 'admin'}},
  { path : 'user' , component : UserComponent , canActivate : [AuthGuardService] , data : { role : 'user'}}
  { path : '**' , component : NotFoundComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**auth-guard.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router , CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../auth-service/auth-service.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
      private router: Router,
      private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const currentUser = this.authService.userVal; // Getting User Value by decoding JWT Token
    const role        = route.data.role; // Getting role value which we passed to data object in router configuration
    if (currentUser) {      
      if(role && role.indexOf(currentUser.role) > -1)
        return true;          
      else 
        return false;          
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

**redirect-guard.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../auth-service/auth-service.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { IUser } from 'client/app/interfaces';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RedirectGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
      private router: Router,
      private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const user = <IUser>this.authService.userVal;
    if (user && user['user']) {      
      this.router.navigate(['/'+ user['user'].role]);
      return true;      
    }      
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. It is just "default" auth guard implementation but not a different component based on the role the logged in user has (admin, user, guest for example)

Comment: Hi @BernoulliIT , Thanks for pointing out the issue. please check the updated answer. For default route, redirect-gudar service will redirect to the route according to user role.

Comment: @ImFarhad what's there in `this.authService.userVal` and `IUser` interface?

Comment: IUser is an interface defined for user. this.authService.userVal is a variable defined in AuthService class

Answer (score -1):

you will certainly find what you need on this page :

https://angular.io/guide/router

But as a quick and dirty answer you can just check if the user is an admin in HomeComponent, and redirect him if it is.